# How to send a measurement from Cumulocity IoT to a registered device using MQTT

Tags: cumulocity

I am able to register a device on Cumulocity IoT and send measurements from the device to Cumuloicty via MQTT. Now I want to send measurement from Cumulocity to that registered device using MQTT. How can I achieve this ?

I tried going through all the documents available on cumulocity but its not mentioned clearly in those docs how we can achieve this flow. I tried the control tab in device which lets us send some single and bulk operations but did not get to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

All communication from Cumulocity IoT to devices is technically covered through operations. Even if maybe in your case the content of the operation is a measurement value, set point or something like this.

The structure of the operation doesn't matter for Cumulocity IoT. Your device in the end needs to understand it.

If you have for example a case where device A sends a measurement (to Cumulocity IoT) and you want device B to receive this measurement you will need to create an operation for device B out of the measurement of device A.

This can be quite easily achieved utilizing the built-in streaming analytics in Cumulocity IoT (see https://cumulocity.com/guides/apama/overview-analytics/). Fastest approach would be the Analytics Builder.

Comment: ok.. thanks for the lead. Will get back if face any issue